# associative array in sort using php

Tags: php, arrays

```
$array = array('0'=>'5', '1'=>'4', '2'=>'1', '3'=>'2');

Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
)
```

Expecting result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)

$array = array('0'=>'5', '1'=>'4', '2'=>'1', '3'=>'2');

$results = [];

foreach($array as $key=>$value){
   $results[$key] = arsort($value);
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($results);
```

Please suggest how do we can sort associative array i did try but does not work for me please guide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your "expected results' it seems like you don't wish to maintain the `keys`. If that's the case then you can just use [`sort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php).

Something like this..

```
$array = array('0'=>'5', '1'=>'4', '2'=>'1', '3'=>'2');
sort($array);
print_r($array);
```

Comment: I appreciated @Md abdul do you have any idea why it call Undefined offset: 4

Comment: I will vote up after 3 min please guide why Undefined offset: 4 called

Comment: maybe you have problem in your loop. check again your loop when printing.

Comment: doing this indexing values are also changing Array
(
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [1] => 4
    [0] => 5
)

Comment: Indexing values also should in sorting sequence Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 4
    [3] => 5
)

Comment: got the idea array_multisort

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate using foreach for sorting 
Just use `sort` for sorting array

```
$array = array('0'=>'5', '1'=>'4', '2'=>'1', '3'=>'2');
sort($array);
print_r($array);
```

This will not maintain array keys and if you want arrays keys to be same just replace `sort` with `asort` in above code

Comment: this gives `Array ( [2] => 1 [3] => 2 [1] => 4 [0] => 5 )`, it dont modify the keys like the OP want in result

Answer (score 0):

Just do

`sort($array);`

Also check the PHP documentation if you need further customization: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 0):

```
var_dump( array_reverse($array,false));
```

you don't need to use foreach or sort ,you can just use `array_reverse`instead ,avery simple way